# JSON with PHP foreach

Tags: php, json

Ok as per your suggestion I updated... By default Laravel returns JSON... I have set it to return an array but I am still getting the same row duplicated using:

```
$limits = array();
    foreach($pieces as $coverage_limit){
            $limits[] = coveragelimit::index($coverage_limit);
        }
    return json_encode($limits);
    }
```

Comment: Just use a php associative array then convert to JSON using json_encode( $limits );

Comment: Not quite clear what you are trying to achieve, but setting $assoc parameter in json_decode to true will convert the json string to  associative array directly.

Comment: So what is the actual question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the $limits array will hold the last value what coveragelimit::index() returns over the iterate, I would suggest a check on coveragelimit::index() return value if it falls with "Marc B"'s answer.

EDIT:

```
foreach($pieces as $key=>$coverage_limit) {
    $limits[$key] = coveragelimit::index($coverage_limit);
}
```

or

```
foreach($pieces as $coverage_limit) {
    array_push($limits, coveragelimit::index($coverage_limit));
}
```

both should returns the same as Marc B's answer

Comment: the question changed, meanwhile :) would you dump the pieces array?

Comment: I'm trying to loop through and return a single json object containing all the values not just the last one, though.

Comment: $pieces var_dump: array
  0 => string 'L0001' (length=5)
  1 => string 'L0002' (length=5)
  2 => string 'L0003' (length=5)

Comment: thanks, as I see the `coveragelimit::index($coverage_limit);` gives you the wrong result

Comment: Well, not the wrong result, just the same one three times (L0001) from the foreach loop.

Comment: to clarify the `coveragelimit::index('L0001');`, `coveragelimit::index('L0002');`, `coveragelimit::index('L0003');` returns the same value and not what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

You're just overwriting `$limits` inside that `foreach()` loop. Perhaps you mean something more like

```
foreach($pieces as $coverage_limit){        
    $limits[] = coveragelimit::index($coverage_limit);
           ^^--- array push?
}
```

As well, you don't "implement" JSON instead of arrays. You work with **NATIVE** data structures, then encode that structure into JSON. JSON's a transport format, it's not something you should ever deal with natively.

Comment: json is just text. You can push it all you want, because PHP just treats it like any other text. Once you run that json through json_decode, it's NOT json anymore. it's a php array or object that you use like any OTHER php array or object.